# Managing layers from a specific group with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have some layers loaded in QGIS, in various groups. I want, with PyQGIS, do some stuff on layers from one of theses groups, like adding geometry type to the layer name.

This way, I can do it on all layers :

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
for layer in layers:
   layer.setName(layer.name()+"_"+QgsWkbTypes.displayString(layer.wkbType()))
```

This way, I can access layer names from one specific group :

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
my_group = root.findGroup('My group')
for layer in my_group.children():
   print(layer.name())
   if isinstance(layer, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
      layer.setName(layer.name()+"_"+QgsWkbTypes.displayString(layer.wkbType()))
```

The "print" of layer name works, but I can't change name, either get the geometry type. I get this error :

```
AttributeError: 'QgsLayerTreeLayer' object has no attribute 'wkbType'
```

Does someone know what is the correct way to do that?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Yes, the Attribute Error (the last line of code in my post)

Comment: I missed that. :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should add `layer()` method to `layer` object. `layer` is an instance of `QgsLayerTreeLayer` and does not have `wkbType` attribute.

Change `layer.wkbType()` to `layer.layer().wkbType()`.
`layer.layer()` returns the map layer associated with `layer`.

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
my_group = root.findGroup('My group')
for layer in my_group.children():
   if isinstance(layer, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
      layer.setName(layer.name() + "_" + QgsWkbTypes.displayString(layer.layer().wkbType()))
```

Answer (score 5):

If each layer of your QGIS project has a **unique name**, you can use the following code.
The loop retrieves the name of the layers of your group then you will identify the layer with the `mapLayersByName` method and you will be able to manipulate it easily.

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
my_group = root.findGroup('My group')

layer_list = [layer.name() for layer in my_group.children()]
for layer in layer_list:
    update_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer)
    for lay in update_layer:
        lay.setName(lay.name()+"_" +QgsWkbTypes.displayString(lay.wkbType()))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, layers can have the same name, and different geometry. For instance, i have "railway_rail" as point, and "railway_way" as line. That's why I want to add the geometry type to the name

Comment: "railway_rail" and "railway_way" don't have the same name. So it's ok.

Comment: my mistake, railway_rail and railway_rail

Comment: I updated my code, it works with your situation. Ask me if you need any explanations

Comment: It works and it's smart, but Kadir Şahbaz' solution is easier and more efficient. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Yes I saw it! his answer is clearly better